# Multiple Related Table with 1:1 Relations. 1st Table with Autonumber

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

```
connection();
String sqlQueryReg = "INSERT INTO  StudentReg(Name, City, Address) VALUES(@Name,@City,@Address)";
SqlCommand cmdReg = new SqlCommand(sqlQueryReg, con);
cmdReg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", model.Name);
cmdReg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", model.City);
cmdReg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", model.Address);

con.Open();
int iReg = cmdReg.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (iReg >= 1)
{
    String sqlQueryInfo = "INSERT INTO  StudentInfo(Id, MotherName, FatherName) VALUES(@Id, @MotherName,@FatherName)";
    SqlCommand cmdInfo = new SqlCommand(sqlQueryInfo, con);
    cmdInfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ????????????????);
    cmdInfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MotherName", model.MotherName);
    cmdInfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatherName", model.FatherName);
    int iInfo = cmdInfo.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
con.Close();
```

For some reason I need to Separate 2 Tables that are related with 1:1 relations [StudentReg] Table contains an autonumber (Identity in SQL Server). After inserting the records in [StudentRecord] I need to [Id] field value bacause I need to insert it in the 2nd Table [StudentInfo]

Expected Output

```
[StudentReg] Table : Note : (Id = Assigned by SQL Server-Identity)
Id | Name | City  | Address
1  | John | ABC   | DEF
2  | Kent | GHI   | PPP

[StudentInfo] Table 
Id | Mother Name | Father Name
1  | Maria       | Jake
2  | Janice      | Frank
```

Comment: Can you provide some input and expected output examples please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Scope_Identity` to get the last inserted identity value in current session and scope

```
declare @StudentRegId int 

INSERT INTO  StudentReg(Name, City, Address) VALUES(@Name,@City,@Address)

select @StudentRegId = scope_identity()

INSERT INTO  StudentInfo(Id, MotherName, FatherName) VALUES(@StudentRegId, @MotherName,@FatherName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope Identity will work if there is an insert trigger, if not you can use ExecuteScalar

```
Int32 savedId;

connection();
String sqlQueryReg = "INSERT INTO  StudentReg(Name, City, Address) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES(@Name,@City,@Address)";
SqlCommand cmdReg = new SqlCommand(sqlQueryReg, con);
cmdReg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", model.Name);
cmdReg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", model.City);
cmdReg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", model.Address);
savedId = (Int32) cmgRed.ExecuteScalar();

con.Open();
int iReg = cmdReg.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (iReg >= 1)
{
    String sqlQueryInfo = "INSERT INTO  StudentInfo(Id, MotherName, FatherName) VALUES(@Id, @MotherName,@FatherName)";
    SqlCommand cmdInfo = new SqlCommand(sqlQueryInfo, con);
    cmdInfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", savedId);
    cmdInfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MotherName", model.MotherName);
    cmdInfo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatherName", model.FatherName);
    int iInfo = cmdInfo.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
con.Close();
```

Additionally check out `.GetLastInsertId()`